# With Argonaut, how can I convert a list of Map(String->Any) to json?

Tags: json, scala, argonaut

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

object Minimal {
  val list = List(Map("id" -> 1), Map("name" -> "Mr. Name"))
  println(list.asJson)
}
```

gives me

```
Error:(8, 16) diverging implicit expansion for type argonaut.EncodeJson[A0]
starting with method IMapEncodeJson in trait EncodeJsons
  println(list.asJson)
               ^
Error:(8, 16) diverging implicit expansion for type argonaut.EncodeJson[V]
starting with method IMapEncodeJson in trait EncodeJsons
  println(list.asJson)
               ^
Error:(8, 16) not enough arguments for method asJson: (implicit e: argonaut.EncodeJson[List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]]])argonaut.Json.
Unspecified value parameter e.
  println(list.asJson)
           ^
```

However, if I redefine list to be

```
  val list = List(Map("id" -> "1"), Map("name" -> "Mr. Name"))
```

it works.

Comment: With this kind of erasure (`Any` val), I doubt Argonaut could find an appropriate instance of the `Encoder` typeclass (indeed pretty sure it won't). I would suggest to refactor to have an explicit/common value type that you know how to encode in JSON (aka a type for which you can define an `Encoder` instance).

Comment: Once just for fun I wrote a horrible macro that provided an `io.circe.Encoder[Any]` instance by enumerating available instances at compile-time and putting them into a runtime map keyed by runtime class. Don't do that.